# Remote IP address with node-js behind amazon ELB

Tags: node.js, ip, amazon-elb

I have a node application on an instance-store amazon machine behind the elastic load balancer (elb). However, the remote IP adress seems to always be the same. I used this code to get the client's IP address in node (via connect/express):

```js
req.socket.remoteAddress
```

I didn't get anything else from the node documentation. Any hint?

Comment: If you're using ELB in TCP mode, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/17981943/201952

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a solution **in case you are using express**:
According to the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#express), you can enable `trust proxy` for your express instance and then `req.ip` will be populated with the correct ip address.

> By enabling the "trust proxy" setting via app.enable('trust proxy'),
>   Express will have knowledge that it's sitting behind a proxy and that
>   the X-Forwarded-* header fields may be trusted, which otherwise may be
>   easily spoofed.
>
> Enabling this setting has several subtle effects. The first of which
>   is that X-Forwarded-Proto may be set by the reverse proxy to tell the
>   app that it is https or simply http. This value is reflected by
>   req.protocol.
>
> The second change this makes is the req.ip and req.ips values will be
>   populated with X-Forwarded-For's list of addresses.

Here's an example:

```
var app = express();
app.enable('trust proxy');
// ...

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('client ip address:', req.ip);
  return next();
});
```

Comment: I was actually using this one for the last few years, but forgot about this question :) thanks for bringing it up again!

Comment: express 4 have changed the way how [`trust proxy`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#trust.proxy.options.table) option is handled, so you can use something like `app.set('trust proxy', 1)` to only trust your load balancer

Comment: By the way, in case of Amazon I think the value has to be `2`, one for the nginx on the actual machine, and another one is the actual load balancer.

Answer (score 8):

The answer worked for me, thanks. But you may just try:

```
var ip_address = null;
if(req.headers['x-forwarded-for']){
    ip_address = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
}
else {
    ip_address = req.connection.remoteAddress;
}
sys.puts( ip_address );
```

Comment: var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;

Comment: There is no `req.connection.remoteAddress` - was it removed in NodeJS?

Answer (score 6):

Your receiving the IP of the ELB instance and you'll need to get the x-forwarded-for value from the headers. Since I'm not a node.js guru, I found this code at http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?id=4500

Example:

```
var http = require( 'http' ),
sys = require( 'sys' );

http.createServer(
        function( req, res ) {
                        var ip_address = null;
                        try {
                                ip_address = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
                        }
                        catch ( error ) {
                                ip_address = req.connection.remoteAddress;
                        }
                        sys.puts( ip_address );
        }
);
```

Comment: Cool thanks, just tried it and it works. I didn't know about that header.

Comment: Is is not an error if `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']` does not exist. `ip_address` will just be `undefined`.

`ip_address = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress`;` will do the job

Answer (score 1):

The selected correct answer here is dangerous, because AWS ELBs switch the order as expected: https://github.com/koajs/koa/issues/1094#issuecomment-345861282

Express, koa, etc. typically take the left-most item, while ELB makes it the right-most item

(express docs):

> If true, the client’s IP address is understood as the left-most entry in the X-Forwarded-For header.

Answer (score 1):

In case if **express.js** is in use:

```
app.set('trust proxy', 2)
```

Instead of

```
app.enable('trust proxy')
```

Because the `app.enable('trust proxy')` uses the leftmost ip from the x-forwarded-for header and so can be easily spoofed by just providing x-forwarded-for header manually.

While the `app.set('trust proxy', 2)` has the number of hops specified that being counted from right to left of the x-forwarded-for header. I.e. if there is an AWS load balancer than 2 will be the right number to count because each new hop ip is added to the end of the x-forwarded-for header.

**If you're using something else** then do the similar way. Just get the `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']`, split by coma and then count hops from  right to left until load balancer ip is not excluded.