# How to use PROXY protocol version 2 to get the client's real IP address?

Tags: node.js, proxy

This question is the same as [How do I use the PROXY protocol to get the client's real IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17981943/784637), however I am trying to implement PROXY protocol version 2 instead of version 1.

I'm using an amazon network load balancer (layer 4) and enabling [PROXY protocol version 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#proxy-protocol) so that the client ip address that the load balancer sees is passed to my server.  Since the load balancer isn't layer 7, I can't capture this information using the `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header.

I was able to parse the PROXY protocol version 1 headers using the recommended [proxywrap](https://github.com/cusspvz/proxywrap#usage) package.

```
var http = require( 'http' )
var proxiedHttp = require( 'findhit-proxywrap' ).proxy( http )
var express = require( 'express' )
var app = express()

// instead of http.createServer(app)
var srv = proxiedHttp.createServer( app ).listen( 80 )

app.get( '/', ( req, res ) => {
    res.send( 'IP = ' + req.connection.remoteAddress + ':' + req.connection.remotePort )
})
```

However PROXY protocol version 2 ["adds support for a binary encoding of the header"](https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt), for which this package currently doesn't support https://github.com/cusspvz/proxywrap/issues/23.

Are there any npm packages I can use to support the PROXY protocol version 2?  How would I implement them for this health check endpoint?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('listening on port %d', port);
});

app.head('/health', (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: Any updates on this issue?